# Application close while changing mode

Tags: android

I have create a application which have to run in both mode. But while changing the mode of application, application is closed. How can I solve this problem

Comment: My crystal ball is not workign right now.  How about some code so we can see what you;re doing?  Maybe a logcat showing the error?

Comment: you mean orientation ? landscape and portrait ?

Comment: @Manisha patel ,when you have any error post in your qusetion and ask question with explanation what you want and what is going on ? and always post logcat in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one in your android menifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

and also put this line in your activity

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Comment: what is need to put this line in activity...can you explain??

Answer (score 2):

Use it in the manifest file of your activity in which you want--

```
< android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

this will never let crash or close your apps.

Hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

this line is used for Landscape orientation.

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

when you want to run your application in both orientation than use this for both orientations.